# Error when adding google playservices to xamarin: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play-services

Error when adding google playservices to xamarin:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.IAPTheme')

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by exception while building google play services component. It is showing only once when you are adding and then building google play services component for the first time. First exception was that Java did not have enough memory and second that this component cannot be build for API 25.

First you have to clear downloaded component. If you can please revert  changes from project which added this component.
1. Remove all data from C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin
2. Remove bin, obj folder from project
3. Remove 'Components' and 'packages' folder which are in your VS solution.
4. Update Java Heap Size - go to project settings then 'Android Options' and 'Advanced' - set Heap Size to '1G'.
5. Do not use API 25 to compile - go to project settings then 'Application' and do not use 'Use latest platform' if you have API 25 installed in Android SDK.
6. If you did not revert your changes form project you have to find a way to add component again. It should be removed from packages.config and also from *.csproj file.
7. Add component from Xamarin Component store, wait a while - it should also add reverences to your project.
8. Rebuild project.